# What's the main differences between isQueryable() vs isSearchable()

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

What's the main differences between isQueryable() vs isSearchable() ?
I couldn't find any reasonable information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former (isQueryable) means that you can use SOQL on an object, the latter (isSearchable) means you can use SOSL on an object. For example, OpportunityLineItem can be queried, but it cannot be searched. Most standard objects can do both, but not all queryable objects are searchable (as demonstrated in this answer). For another example, EmailStatus can neither be queried nor searched, only described. I'm not specifically aware any objects that can be searched, but not queried, though, but it is technically possible for this configuration to exist as well.